# Single template instantiation for separate objects

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following:

```
/* T.h */
template <class T>
void Too() {
    std::cout << "  Template: " << typeid(T).name()
              << " size: " << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
}
```

```
/* A.h */
extern void FooA();
```

```
/* A.cpp */
struct Local {
    int a[2];
}

void FooA() {
    Local l;
    std::cout << "<Foo A>:\n" << "  Real: " << typeid(l).name()
              << " size: " << sizeof(l) << std::endl;
    Too<Local>();
}
```

```
/* B.h */
extern void FooB();
```

```
/* B.cpp */
struct Local {
    int a[4];
};

void FooB() {
    Local l;
    std::cout << "<Foo B>:\n" << "  Real: " << typeid(l).name() \
              << " size: " << sizeof(l) << std::endl;
    Too<Local>();
}
```

```
/* main.cpp */
int main() {
    FooA();
    FooB();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running results in:

```
<Foo A>:
  Real: 5Local size: 8
  Template: 5Local size: 8
<Foo B>:
  Real: 5Local size: 16
  Template: 5Local size: 8
```

Which means that single template instantiation was used for both template calls. Notably -- the first one.
While it is possible to workaround this 'feature' by defining `Too()` as

```
template <class T, size_t s = sizeof(T)> Too();
```

I wanted to know are there any more generic approaches to this problem? Since above code will still fail if two calling structures are of same size.

**EDIT:**

Specifically my problem lies in the fact, that I can not change the files A and B. So I may not introduce anonymous namespaces to them. 
Are there any template side solutions? Hence the second template parameter.

Comment: I may misunderstand this, but it seems you are breaking the One Definition Rule and so get undefined behavoir. You have 2 different structs in your program called 'Local' in the global namespace.

Comment: Wrap the `struct Local` in an anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 7):

Your program violates ODR (One Definition Rule) by containing two definitions of `struct Local`. Which means it's ill-formed and has Undefined Behaviour, so anything can happen.

Comment: Why none of my tested compilers warn about this? (clang and MSVC++11)

Comment: You have shown what's wrong, but didn't answer the question / provided a solution...

Comment: @vytis The standard doesn't require a compiler to detect ODR violations; the reason is that in a traditional setup, the *compiler* only knows about a single translation unit, and the *linker* doesn't know about structs.

Comment: @leemes I must say I couldn't find a question besides "why doesn't it work?" Note that if the ODR violation is removed (i.e. each `struct` will be a distinct type), then of course each call to `Too` will have its own instantiation.

Answer (score 6):

As has been pointed out, you have violated the One Definition Rule.

You could define your local structs in anonymous namespaces, so that the compiler knows that you're talking about different local types, then everything should "work":

```
/* A.cpp */
namespace {
    struct Local {
        int a[2];
    }
}

/* B.cpp */
namespace {
    struct Local {
        int a[4];
    }
}
```